# error when run tf.SVD on GPU - tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to run code that uses tf.SVD on GPU, but it gives me this error:

```
No registered 'Svd' OpKernel for GPU devices compatible with node Svd = Svd[T=DT_FLOAT, compute_uv=true, full_matrices=false](x)
.  Registered:  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
   device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
   device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
   device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that this operations is not available for GPU. So your options are:

1. sit and wait till someone will implement it
2. use CPU version
3. implement it for yourself.